# GWT paging widget

Tags: gwt, pagination, widget

I'm looking for a GWT common purpose paging widget.
So far I have found [GWT widget library](http://gwt-widget.sourceforge.net/) and the 
[Google Incubator widgets](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/w/list). 
Is there any other free (possibly open source) widget library implementing a paging behavior.

Comment: GWT 2.1 ships with paging functionality now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231407/gwt-paging-widget/4216573#4216573

Comment: I know ... but the question was asked back in ancient times where GWT 1.6 was the last state of the art.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the two major ones.  The Google Incubator widgets might be a good bet, because the intention is for these to eventually make it into the main library.  In general the GWT widget library widgets tend to be fancier, but the GWT incubator library widgets tend to be more modular and also more robust across more web browsers.

Comment: I have tried both. The Google incubator has currently some unresolved issues and I'm not willing go with it to production. The GWT widget library looks promising but there is no examples to see it in action, plus the documentation is very thin.

Comment: I have copied the gwt-widget paging principle and created my own one, more suited to what I need.

Comment: this isn't the best solution anymore since GWT now ships with paging functionality.

Answer (score 5):

GWT 2.1 now ships with paging widgets.

[Cell Table with paging](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)

[Data Presentation Widgets (Cell Widgets)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html)

[How to use GWT 2.1 Data Presentation Widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891803/how-to-use-gwt-2-1-data-presentation-widgets/2944454#2944454)

[com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have used the one offered by GXT (A GWT library) and I love it!  Check it out!

http://extjs.com/products/gxt/

Comment: Thing is, that's not very suitable for production unless people are willing to pay for the library, which in 99% of the cases they don't. Having said that, I have used it in the past and loved it very much.

Comment: I'll add that in hindsight, I like the widget but very much dislike the company even with the paid support plan. Until ExtJS LLC (now Sencha inc) increases the resources to GXT, I can't recommend it as a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This GXT library have a commercial lisence!

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm not using it. I have written my own paging which suits my needs more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they do both comerical and quid pro quo

http://extjs.com/company/dual.php

So provided you open source your project you can use it for free.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an example of using GWT 2.1 `CellTable` with the `AsyncDataProvider`:
http://robin.mytechtip.com/2010/11/17/gwt-celltable-example-using-asyncdataprovider/