# Best pageable table implementation in GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to add a paging, sortable table to my GWT application.

I see lots of these out there so I'm looking for your experience to save me time by choosing the best one.

So far I'm looking at...

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-advanced-table/
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/PagingScrollTableOld

I like the second one best. Any stories to tell?

Answer (score 16):

There's a new CellTable that has support for paging. It's in the GWT trunk right now and will, with any luck, make it into a 2.1 release later this year.

Comment: @Steve I'm sure Isaac wouldn't mind if you accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231407/gwt-paging-widget)

And unfortunately there is no satisfying implementation available.
The best approach i have found has the [GWT widget library](http://gwt-widget.sourceforge.net/). I have used it to create my own paging solution.

Answer (score 0):

I completely disagree that there is no suitable solution.  You really need to check out GXT.  I am using the Paging Grid implementation in my organization with great success.

http://extjs.com/products/gxt/

Comment: This is true, but however this is no native GWT implementation, plus the Ext GWT library is not completly free (as it was some time ago)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'free'. Just to clarify: GXT = ExtGWT, which is dual-licenced as GPLv3 or a commercial licence. It used to be MyGWT which was dual as well, but GLPL and commercial.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using gwtlib [http://code.google.com/p/gwtlib/] its a nice expendable solution that uses the Controller Pattern, I have been using it in some personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that GXT is the best solution, but, as i said before, it has a commercial license  in this way any non open source project has to pay for it!