# AsyncListViewAdapter + SimplePager, why is inactive pager clearing the table?

Tags: gwt, dataview

EDIT: This seems to be [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4988&sort=-id).

I'm trying to make CellTable work together with **AsyncListViewAdapter**<T> and SimplePager<T>. The data gets displayed, but when the pager should be 'deaf' (meaning when all existing data are displayed) it still receives clicks and, more importantly, makes the displayed data go away. Instead of my data 'loading' indicator gets displayed, and it keep loading and loading... Obviously nothing gets loaded, as it doesn't even call the onRangeChanged handler.

I went through the code-snippets in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891803/how-to-use-gwt-2-1-data-presentation-widgets), but I can't see anything suspicions on what I've been doing.

Is there some obvious answer to a rookie mistake?

I shrinked my variable names, hopefully it won't wrap too much.

```
protected class MyAsyncAdapter
  extends AsyncListViewAdapter<DTO> {
  @Override
  protected void onRangeChanged(ListView<DTO> v) {
    /*
     * doesn't even get called on [go2start/go2end] click :(
     */
    Range r = v.getRange();
    fetchData(r.getStart(), r.getLength());
  }
}

private void addTable() {
  // table:
  CellTable<DTO> table = new CellTable<DTO>(10);
  table.addColumn(new Column<DTO, String>(new TextCell()) {
      @Override
      public String getValue(DTO myDto) {
        return myDto.getName();
      }
    }, "Name");

  // pager:
  SimplePager<DTO> pager = new SimplePager<DTO>(table);
  table.setPager(pager);

  adapter = new MyAsyncAdapter();
  adapter.addView(table);
  // does not make any difference:
  // adapter.updateDataSize(0, false);
  // adapter.updateDataSize(10, true);

  VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  vPanel.add(table);
  vPanel.add(pager);
  RootLayoutPanel.get().add(vPanel);
}

// success-handler of my fetching AsyncCallback
@Override
public void onSuccess(List<DTO> data) {
  // AsyncCallback<List<DTO>> has start field
  adapter.updateViewData(start, data.size(), data);
  if(data.size() < length)
    adapter.updateDataSize(start + data.size(), true);
}
```

Regards
  J. Záruba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently because of [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4988&can=5).