# GWT Selectable Grid

Tags: gwt, grid, selectable

Does anyone know of a good selectable grid for gwt google web toolkit?  I need this functionality ported over for my application.  Just for example I would like it work similar to pfselect for the jquery library.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is on the way in GWT2.1. Currently milestone version is available. Probably you can give a try. I would suggest not to use smartgwt or ext-gwt. Because at initial page load it downloads lots of javascript.

Please have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891803/how-to-use-gwt-2-1-data-presentation-widgets)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at

- GWT Incubator ScrollTable (http://collectionofdemos.appspot.com/demo/index.html)
- SmartGWT grid (http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/)
- Ext GWT (from Ext-JS)