# Data Presentation Widgets + MVP

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I am trying to use the new Data Presentation Widgets (cellTable)

Now for a demo I am making, I used the example from here [How to use GWT 2.1 Data Presentation Widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891803/how-to-use-gwt-2-1-data-presentation-widgets) to create a button in a column for each row.

My understanding of MVP is that I would need to expose the HasClickEvents to my presenter from my view.  How do I accomplish this?

Right now I have

```
projectGrid.addColumn(new Column<DataDTO, DataDTO>(new ActionCell<DataDTO>("Assign", new Delegate<DataDTO>() {
            public void execute(DataDTO row) {
                //Attach it here?
                Window.alert(row.toString());

            }
        })) {

            @Override
            public DataDTO getValue(DataDTO object) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return object;
            }


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Delegate#execute()` is the right place to invoke the callback to the presenter. There are a couple of ways you can do this but I find it easier to give my views a handle to their presenter and then define callback methods on the presenter:

```
class MyPresenter {
  public void onAssign() {
    // Perform action.
  }
}

class MyView {
  private MyPresenter presenter;

  public MyView() {
    projectGrid.addColumn(
      new Column<DataDTO, DataDTO>(
        new ActionCell<DataDTO>("Assign", new Delegate<DataDTO>() {
          public void execute(DataDTO row) {
            presenter.onAssign();
          }
        })) {...});
  }
```